Start-Processes with multiple Paths in Variable
The various paths from the variable "$EXECleanUninstallStringsX86" are always transferred all at once and not individually. Although two processes are started for two paths, the paths of both processes always include all paths from the variable:
This command cannot be run due to the error: An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\Uninstall.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\Test.exe' with working directory 'C:\PatchTemp'.

Here is the relevant part from my script:
$DisplayNameX86 = "7-Zip*"
$EXEUninstallArgumentsX86 = "/S"

# Uninstall (EXE/X86)
If ($DisplayNameX86 -ne "") {
$EXEUninstallStringsX86 = Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like $DisplayNameX86 -and $_.UninstallString -like "*.exe*" -and $_.UninstallString -notlike "*MsiExec*"} | Select-Object Publisher,DisplayName,DisplayVersion,UninstallString
If ($EXEUninstallStringsX86 -ne $null) {
ForEach ($EXEUninstallStringX86 in $EXEUninstallStringsX86){
$EXECleanUninstallStringsX86 = ($EXEUninstallStringsX86.UninstallString -Replace '.exe.*','.exe' -Replace '"','')
Start-Process -FilePath "$EXECleanUninstallStringsX86" -ArgumentList "$EXEUninstallArgumentsX86" -Wait -PassThru
Write-Host "EXE-Uninstallation(s) for x86 started" -f Green
}
} Else {
Write-Host "EXE-UninstallString(s) for x86 not found" -f Yellow
}
}

This is what the content of a variable "$EXECleanUninstallStringsX86" looks like, for example:
C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\Uninstall.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\Test.exe

I have tested countless variants (e.g. cmd /c) without success.

You're using the array variable $EXEUninstallStringsX86 instead of the loop variable $EXEUninstallStringX86 inside your loop. I'd recommend to us more speaking variable names. If it's an array or a list I'd have the actual word "list" in the variable name.  ☝  ... somthing like UninstallString_List

Isn't that a bad joke? I have been looking for the error all day and the cause is the wrong name of the variable. I am totally desperate because I was sure that the basic structure was correct. This clearly shows that you are right. I will give the variables more meaningful names in future. Thank you!

The cause was that I used the wrong variable within the foreach-loop. Here is the correct script:
$DisplayNameX86 = "7-Zip*"
$EXEUninstallArgumentsX86 = "/S"

# Uninstall (EXE/X86)
If ($DisplayNameX86 -ne "") {
$EXEUninstallStringsX86 = Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like $DisplayNameX86 -and $_.UninstallString -like "*.exe*" -and $_.UninstallString -notlike "*MsiExec*"} | Select-Object Publisher,DisplayName,DisplayVersion,UninstallString
If ($EXEUninstallStringsX86 -ne $null) {
ForEach ($EXEUninstallStringX86 in $EXEUninstallStringsX86){
$EXECleanUninstallStringsX86 = ($EXEUninstallStringX86.UninstallString -Replace '.exe.*','.exe' -Replace '"','')
Start-Process -FilePath "$EXECleanUninstallStringsX86" -ArgumentList "$EXEUninstallArgumentsX86" -Wait -PassThru
Write-Host "EXE-Uninstallation(s) for x86 started" -f Green
}
} Else {
Write-Host "EXE-UninstallString(s) for x86 not found" -f Yellow
}
}

